# What to do when a module is uninstalled but leaves some features enabled?

Tags: features

I just disabled and uninstalled a module. Problem is that I still see some features that were created by this module at: "admin/structure/features"

How can I delete these features? I don't see any "features" table in the database.

**UPDATE**
I think I wasn't clear enough, sorry. It is not a feature module, it is standar module called "md_portfolio". This module creates the features you can see in the capture.

There are not any modules with the names you see in the capture in **sites/all/modules**

**Update2** the features are shown as "enabled" in the capture but NOW they are disabled (I took this capture when I had them enabled)

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to file system?

Comment: Features are usually in sites/all/modules. If you want a feature to be disabled when a certain module is disabled, then add a dependency on that module to your feature.

Comment: @Dmytro yes I have

Comment: As @beebee said, feature are stored in sites/all/modules/features/*
Can't you simple delete features from file system?
It can be that some files have not been deleted from feature folder.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: please take a look at my update

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

If the feature is creating some items that you no longer wish to have on your site (content type, maybe) you can always uninstall that feature. Remember features are basically modules, so you uninstall them the same way (go to mysite/admin/modules/uninstall). That may start to remove some of the items the feature was responsible for (depending on the feature's uninstall script)

Also, as features are basically mini modules, they won't fully go away (or stop showing up on your features page) without removing them first. They should be located in your site/all/modules folder. Remove the feature from the file system.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough, sorry. Please take a look at my update

Comment: @chefnelone What are the contents of the md_portfolio module? Are there any subfolders in there? Any files with names along the lines of md_portfolio_blog.feature.features.inc?I looked up that module and it looks like a proprietary module (not contributed), and it's likely the developers wrapped the features into the module to make it more portable and easier to set up.

Comment: Ok, I just deleted the module folder, run cron, update database, clear all caches. I get deleted all the Features. Now I only have a content type which was not deleted. The delete link for it is missing. How can I delete it?

Comment: Just to double check, did you uninstall the module at mysite/admin/modules/uninstall before deleting it from your server?